# Camunda 7 Community Edition volume limitations

Tags: camunda, camunda-modeler

I'm testing various workflow management solutions. This is how I met Camunda. Studying it as a product it seems very valid, but unfortunately, I can't find in the documentation a scheme where the limits of the simultaneous instances that can be managed with the community version are specified.
Does anyone have any idea of this info or know where to get it?
I would need this information for version 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such limitation with Camunda 7 Community Edition.

Actually this is an open source product under Apache License V2:

- https://github.com/camunda/camunda-bpm-platform/blob/master/LICENSE
- https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.18/introduction/licenses/

As I know, for Enterprise Edition pricing will depend on your
activity instances counts for some period of time.

Also there is comparison of CE vs EE:
https://camunda.com/platform-7/editions/

Answer (score 1):

You can run as many process instances simultaneously as your database can handle. The engine does not differ between Camunda 7 CE and EE. Here you can find some sizing recommendations: https://docs.camunda.io/docs/components/best-practices/operations/performance-tuning-camunda-c7/

If you are interested in very high volumes, you may also want to take a look at Camunda 8, which has a fundamentally different architecture to achieve higher throughputs.